# Why is this call to IDBObjectStore.get() is resulting in confusing behavior?

Tags: javascript, debugging, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I am trying to get the hang of using indexedDB to store data client side.

consider the following code:

```
function queryURL(message, sender)
{
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll();

    var openRequest = indexedDB.open("Tags",1);
    openRequest.onsuccess = function(event){
        var queryURL = message['host'];
        var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.transaction("domains").objectStore("domains");
        var query = objectStore.get(queryURL);

        query.onsuccess = function(event){                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            alert(query.result);
            delete query.result["domain"];
            createMenuItems(query.result);
            available_commands=request.result;        
        };

        db.onerror = function(event){
            console.log("an error bubbled up during a transaction.");
        };

    };
    openRequest.onerror = function(event){
        console.log("error opening DB");
    };  
}
```

---

I do not fully understand what should be happening in the query.

**The result is the same whether or not the key that is queried for is in the database:** 
`query.onsuccess()` runs and `query.result` is `undefined` so the
   code errors and exits as soon as I try to delete a key from
   `query.result`.

If the key **is not** found, `query.onsuccess()` should **not** be
   running, correct?

If the key **is** found, `query.result` should hold the object that
   corresponds to that key, correct?

---

In case it helps, here is the code that I used to initialize the database:

```
const db_name="Tags";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          


var request = window.indexedDB.open(db_name, 1); 
var tags  = [ 
    //codes: 0 - markdown wrap tag
    //       1 - HTML wrap tag 
    //       2 - single tag
    { domain: "www.youtube.com", 

      bold:["*",0],
      strikethrough:["-",0],
      italic:["_",0] 
    },  


    { domain: "www.stackoverflow.com", 

      bold:["<strong>",1], 
      italic:["<em>",1],
      strikethrough:["<del>",1],
      superscript:["<sup>",1],
      subscript:["<sub>",1],
      heading1:["<h1>",1],
      heading2:["<h2>",1],
      heading3:["<h3>",1],
      blockquote:["<blockquote>",1],
      code:["<code>",1],
      newline:["<br>",2],
      horizontal:["<hr>",2]
    }   
];


request.onerror = function(event) {
  alert("Error opening the database");
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    alert("I'm doing stuff!"); 
    var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("domains", {keyPath: "domain" }); 
    objectStore.createIndex("domain", "domain", { unique: true }); 

    objectStore.transaction.onComplete = function(event) {
        var domanStore=db.transaction("domains","readwrite").objectStore("domains");
        for(var i in tags)
        {
            domainStore.add(tags[i]);
        }
    }   
};
```

Here are some links to the resources I am using:

[Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

[IDBObjectStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore)

[IDBRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest)

Comment: Where is this code located?

Comment: @Xan It is in an event page. Feel free to ask, if you want to see more parts of the code

Comment: Are you looking in the right console for errors?

Comment: @Xan durr, the one that comes up when i select "inspect element" in the chrome context menu? I have also looked at the one you get when you click the link provided at the extension page. (Both show no errors related to my extension)

Comment: Then you're looking at the console for the current tab. Go to `chrome://extensions/` and click the background page for your extension to bring up the correct console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69049/discussion-between-lukep-and-xan).

Comment: **Do not update the question with new questions**, or ask follow-up questions in comments. Your existing question was answered in a satisfactory manner. If you modify your question significantly after that, it invalidates existing answers. Make a new question if you have follow-up questions. As always, please take another look at [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding out that the result is empty or undefined is a successful query. So yes, you get `onsuccess` call with `result === undefined`.

`onerror` is only reserved for when something *breaks*, e.g. you supplied an invalid key.

From [`IDBObjectStore.get` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore.get):

> **Note:** This method produces the same result for: a) a record that doesn't exist in the database and b) a record that has an undefined value. To tell these situations apart, call the `openCursor()` method with the same key. That method provides a cursor if the record exists, and no cursor if it does not.

Comment: That is helpful, and is what I was beginning to suspect.  BUT, why is query.result udefined when I navigate to, stackoverflow.com, which is in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is even more confusing when `delete` method return success, even if no record is deleted.

Since request error event is cancellable bubbling event, it is not feasible to invoke to error callback even if no record is found. If request is on error and error is not prevented, its transaction will be aborted and `indexedDB.onerror` will be called as well. So invoking success with undefined result is still better than invoking error.